# Como contar o número de linhas dentro de um div que não possui "limitador de linhas"?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Como posso contar o número de linhas em um *div* que não possua um `\n` ou um `<br>` no final de cada linha? Exemplificando:

```js
var el = document.getElementById('theDiv');
    lines = el.innerHTML.replace(/ |^\s+|\s+$/g,'').split('\n'),
    lineCount = lines.length;

alert(lineCount); // 5 = correto.
```

```css
div {
    background: #333;
    color: #fff;
    max-width: 60px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id='theDiv'>
    AAAAA
    BBBBB
    CCCCC
    DDDDD
    EEEEE
</div>
```

Ao final de cada linha há um `\n`, então é simples de fazer essa contagem somente utilizando um **`split()`**. Mas o problema é: E quando não existe esse "limite" entre uma linha e outra?

Considere o caso da "quebra" ser feita por uma regra no CSS que define uma largura máxima para o *div*, por exemplo:

```js
var el = document.getElementById('theDiv');
    lines = el.innerHTML.replace(/ |^\s+|\s+$/g,'').split('\n'),
    lineCount = lines.length;

alert(lineCount); // vai mostrar 1...
```

```css
div {
    background: #333;
    color: #fff;
    max-width: 60px; /* O css limita a largura e 'quebra' a linha */
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id='theDiv'>AAAAA BBBBB CCCCC DDDDD EEEEE</div>
```

O **`alert()`** exibido não está errado, realmente existe uma única linha. Mas, **visualmente** falando, existem 5 linhas como no exemplo anterior.

Como posso fazer essa contagem de linhas?

---

<sub>A princípio estou buscando uma resposta sem o uso de *frameworks*, mas uma resposta utilizando jQuery certamente ajudará e será muito bem vinda.</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Além da largura, defina o `line-height` do elemento através do css:

```
div {
    max-width: 60px;
    line-height: 14px;
}
```

E com o javascript apenas divida a altura do elemento pela altura da linha:

```
var minhaDiv = document.getElementById("conteudo"),
    estiloComputado = window.getComputedStyle(minhaDiv),
    alturaDiv = minhaDiv.offsetHeight,
    alturaLinha = parseInt(estiloComputado.getPropertyValue("line-height"));

alert(alturaDiv / alturaLinha);
```

Exemplo funcionando no [SQLFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dq03w324/1/).

Comment: Se o `line-height` não estiver definido, ainda assim é possível obtê-lo?

Comment: Pesquisei rapidamente e não encontrei nada sobre. @renan

Comment: Funcionou mesmo sem definir `line-height` .

Answer (score 2):

Surgiu-me esta ideia: colocar um `<span>` à volta de cada caractere e verificar se a posição vertical é a mesma que o próximo. Se não fôr então houve mudança de linha :)

Claro que isto implica que não haja CSS aplicado a `#theDiv span` mas isso é fácil de fazer um reset.

```
var text = $('#theDiv').text();
var newText = text.split('').map(function (letra) {
    return ['<span>', letra, '</span>'].join('');
}).join('');
$('#theDiv').html(newText);

var linhas = 1;
var ultimaLinha;
$('#theDiv span').each(function () {
    var pos = this.getBoundingClientRect().bottom;
    if (ultimaLinha && pos != ultimaLinha) linhas++;
    ultimaLinha = pos;
});
alert(linhas); // 5
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/91pmfghq/

Comment: Estou tentando entender, as vezes me perco nas funções do jQuery.

Comment: @renan a primeira parte põe um 'span' à volta de cada letra ou espaço. A segunda parte percorre cada span/letra e vai ver a posiçao que a span/letra tem e compara para saber se mudou de linha.